How to demonstrate that $iH \in \mathfrak{sp}(2n)/\mathfrak{u}(n)$ given specific unitary matrices?
The $H$ is a Hermitian matrix, there exist two unitary matrix $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that
$$
U_1 H^* U_1^\dagger=H\hspace{1cm}U_2 H^* U_2^\dagger=-H
$$
where $U_1$ is a symmetric matrix and $U_2$ is a skew-symmetric matrix. How can we demonstrate that $iH\in \mathfrak{sp}(2n)/\mathfrak{u}(n)$?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
